# iOS - How to reduce alpha of UINavigationBar titleView whilst scrolling UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am looking for a way to reduce the UINavigationBar titleView alpha channel to zero whilst scrolling down a UITableView and do the reverse whilst scrolling up.

Is there any clean way to do so using the scrollViewDidScroll delegate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Super simple, just drop this into a table view controller in a navigation controller:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1 - (self.tableView.contentOffset.y / (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height));
}
```

Subtracting `self.tableView.frame.size.height` is because the `contentOffset` is set from the top, so even at the lowest position will be separated by width of the frame; the 0-100 range is 0 to the (`contentSize.height` - `frame.size.height`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the contentOffset value of the scrollView to determine its distance from the top and therefore set the alpha accordingly.